# Find the sum of two arrays with different length in C Programming

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to add two arrays with different length (`arr1[6]` and `arr2[9]`). The code that I have been able to write so far is as follows>>

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define maxElements 100

int main()
{
    int n1,n2,arr1[maxElements],arr2[maxElements],i,temp,c[maxElements];

    // number of elements of the array 1

    printf("How many elements will the array 1 have \n");
    scanf(" %d",&n1);

    // number of elements of the array 2

        printf("How many elements will the array 2 have \n");
            scanf(" %d",&n2);

    // taking the elements of array 1

    printf("Enter the elements of array 1\n");

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d",&arr1[i]);
    }

    // taking the elements of array 2

    printf("Enter the elements of array 2\n");

    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d",&arr2[i]);
    }

  // adding the elements of array 1 and array 2

   if(n1>=n2)
   {
       for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
       {

           c[i]=arr1[i]+arr2[i];
       }
   }
   else
   {
       for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
       {
           c[i]=arr1[i]+arr2[i];

       }
   }

   //print the output

   printf("The output of addition of 2 arrays is\n");

if(n1>=n2)
   {
       for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
       {
           printf("%d\n",c[i]);
       }
   }
   else
   {
       for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
       {
           printf("%d\n",c[i]);
       }
   }

}
```

When I input the number of elements and the elements of the two arrays, for example:

```
How many elements will the array 1 have:
6

How many elements will the array 2 have:
9

Enter the elements of array 1:
3 5 2 7 1 8

Enter the elements of array 2:
7 9 2 4 1 6 8 5 3
```

I get the following result :

```
10
14
4
11
2
14
7864429
50397191
3
```

The result is slightly different from the expected result

```
10 14 4 11 2 14 8 5 3
```

**Can somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?**

> P.S. I apologise if there are any spelling mistakes or grammar errors.

Comment: Try seeding the values of the c array with a constant and see what happens.

Comment: When you declare a variable in C, in most cases it contains junk data until you initialize it — this includes the elements of an array before you assign to them. To make every element of an array 0, declare it like this: `int arr[5] = {};`

Comment: @RayHamel  - That one did it , I appreciate everyone's help especially yours. Thanks again.

Comment: do not put new lines after prompt lines so that the user input lies on the same line

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong if you fill array beyond of its limit. Like your arr1 has capacity of storing 6 element but you are going to fill value in arr1[6] to arr1[8]. You may get corruption error. For your logic, if n1 is less then n2 then run loop only till n1. So that arr2 and arr1 will increase itself until loop reach n1 and remaining part of arr2 will intact. So you will not get weird output.

Answer (score 0):

In your example where you say:

```
   if(n1>=n2)
   {
     for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
     {

       c[i]=arr1[i]+arr2[i];
     }
    }
```

once `i` is going above 6 (the value of `n2`) it is trying to access an element in `arr2` that doesn't exist; therefore it is just returning random numbers instead, unlike the 0 you seem to expect.

Either initialize all elements as 0 before-hand or take a look at vectors.

Comment: Or, once you've reached the smaller of `n1`, `n2`, only use the values from the longer array.

Comment: In your example arr1 has 9 elements.

Comment: In your example arr1 has 6 elements, arr2 has 9 elements. When you try to add the 7th element of arr1 to arr2 is when your problem occurs. This is because there is no value for the 7th element.

Answer (score 0):

It is accessing elements that do not exist.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < min(n1, n2); i++){
      c[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because of garbage value. This happens when you try to access array value beyond its range or some compilers will give index out of range error.

Solution is,
Add the respective elements from both array till the length of smaller array. keep the rest of the elements of bigger array as it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n1,n2,arr1[100]={0},arr2[100]={0},i,c[100];

    printf("Size of Array 1 \n");
    scanf(" %d",&n1);


        printf("Size of array 2 \n");
            scanf(" %d",&n2);


    printf("Enter the elements of array 1\n");

    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d",&arr1[i]);
    }


    printf("Enter the elements of array 2\n");

    for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %d",&arr2[i]);
    }


   if(n1>=n2)
   {
       for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
           c[i]=arr1[i]+arr2[i];
   }
   else
   {
       for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
           c[i]=arr1[i]+arr2[i];

   }

   printf("Array after sum\n");

if(n1>=n2)
   {
       for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
           printf("%d\n",c[i]);
   }
   else
   {
       for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
           printf("%d\n",c[i]);
   }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[100], b[100], c[100], i, j, n, m, max, min;
    clrscr();
    printf("N = ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        printf("a[%d] = ",i);
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("M = ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    for(i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        printf("b[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d",&b[i]);
    }
    max=n;
    min=m;
    if(m>n)
    {
        max=m;
        min=n;
    }
    for(i=0; i<max; i++)
    {
        if(i<min)
        {
            c[i] = a[i] + b[i];
        }
        else
        {
            if(max==n)
            {
                c[i] = a[i];
            }
            else
            {
                c[i] = b[i];
            }
        }
        printf("\nc[%d] = %d",i, c[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score -2):

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   #include<conio.h>
 int main()
   {
          int a1[8],a2[5],a3[13],i,j,num;

          printf("\nEnter 1st array value:");
          for(i=0;i<8;i++)
          {
             printf("\nEnter 1st Array Element:");
             scanf("%d",&a1[i]);
          }

          printf("\n\nEnter 2nd array value:");
          for(i=0;i<5;i++)
          {
             printf("\nEnter 2nd Array Element:");
             scanf("%d",&a2[i]);
          }

          printf("\n1st Array :");
          for(i=0;i<8;i++)
          printf("  %d",a1[i]);

          printf("\n2nd Array :");
          for(i=0;i<5;i++)
          printf("  %d",a2[i]);

          for(i=0;i<13;i++)
          {
                  if(i<8)
                         a3[i] = a1[i];
                  else
                         a3[i] = a2[i-8];
          }

          printf("\nAfter Marge :");
          for(i=0;i<13;i++)
          printf("  %d",a3[i]);

          getch();
          return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note that the asker's code is trying to perform the *sum of the values* of two differently-sized array, while the code you posted seems to *concatenate* two arrays having two arbitrary chosen fixed sizes.